# Merge based on a numeric value matrix in R (string)

Tags: string, r, merge

I would like to merge two dataframes based on the on a numeric best match value. I am using levenshteinSim() to generate a numeric match between characters. I would like to use that number to match observations for a merge. For example:

```
f1 <- data.frame(x = c("apple", "banana", "dark"), y = c(1,2,3))
f2 <- data.frame(x = as.character(c("ark", "appl", "bannana")), z = c(1,2,3))

mat <- sapply(as.character(f1$x), levenshteinSim, str2= as.character(f2$x))
```

This generates the following matrix in which the highest value corresponds to a match:

```
     apple    banana      dark
[1,] 0.2000000 0.1666667 0.7500000
[2,] 0.8000000 0.1666667 0.0000000
[3,] 0.1428571 0.8571429 0.1428571
```

Any help on then merging the two dataframes by the x variable according to the corresponding highest matches would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the matches using:

```
matches = names(mat)[apply(mat, 1, FUN=which.max)]
```

That gives ["dark", "apple", "banana"]. This is the match to f2 in order so to merge the two data frames try:

```
out = data.frame(f2x=f2$x, f1match = matches)
```

Is that what you were after?

Answer (score 1):

Use apply to get the indices of the highest matches, and replace the y column of f1 with the reordered matches:

```
f1[,2] <- apply(mat, 2, which.max)
```

Then simply merge the two together

```
merge(f1, f2, by.x="y", by.y="z")
```

Comment: Thanks, this code gets almost there, but it needs to preserve the other variables rather than replace them for a merge.